# startup program exits with code 126 when executing program at entrypoint

Tags: x86, gdb, elf, x86-64

I want to reverse engineer a program. I managed to find the entry point but every time I want to launch the application I get the same error `During startup program exited with code 126.

Here is what I did:

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Documents/Guessy]
└─$ gdb guessy\?token=eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxNDM4LCJ0ZWFtX2lkIjpudWxsLCJmaWxlX2lkIjoxNjd9.YIyJZA.QQbX2E3vChspI95coiZvSzAwDOo
GNU gdb (Debian 10.1-1.7) 10.1.90.20210103-git
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.                                                                                                                                                                                            
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from guessy?token=eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxNDM4LCJ0ZWFtX2lkIjpudWxsLCJmaWxlX2lkIjoxNjd9.YIyJZA.QQbX2E3vChspI95coiZvSzAwDOo...
(No debugging symbols found in guessy?token=eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxNDM4LCJ0ZWFtX2lkIjpudWxsLCJmaWxlX2lkIjoxNjd9.YIyJZA.QQbX2E3vChspI95coiZvSzAwDOo)
(gdb) break 1
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
(gdb) break 0x0000000000006160
Function "0x0000000000006160" not defined.
Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) 
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/kali/Documents/Guessy/guessy?token=eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxNDM4LCJ0ZWFtX2lkIjpudWxsLCJmaWxlX2lkIjoxNjd9.YIyJZA.QQbX2E3vChspI95coiZvSzAwDOo 
zsh:1: permission denied: /home/kali/Documents/Guessy/guessy?token=eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxNDM4LCJ0ZWFtX2lkIjpudWxsLCJmaWxlX2lkIjoxNjd9.YIyJZA.QQbX2E3vChspI95coiZvSzAwDOo
During startup program exited with code 126.
```

I found the entrypoint with this:

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Documents/Guessy]
└─$ objdump -f /bin/ls                                                                                                                                                                                                                 130 ⨯

/bin/ls:     file format elf64-x86-64
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000150:
HAS_SYMS, DYNAMIC, D_PAGED
start address 0x0000000000006160
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program exiting with code 126 in GDB occurs when the current user does not have execute permissions for the binary being debugged:

```
$ ls -l test
-rw-r--r-- 1 user01 user01 110080 May  1 22:18 test

$ gdb -q test
...
gef➤  run
Starting program: /home/user01/test 
/bin/bash: /home/user01/test: Permission denied
/bin/bash: line 0: exec: /home/user01/test: cannot execute: Permission denied
During startup program exited with code 126.
```

Please note that when setting a break point to a specific address like `0x0000000000006160`, an asterisk must be used:

1. `break * 0x0000000000006160` or `break *0x0000000000006160`

The following will result in an error:

2. `break 0x0000000000006160`

In (2), GDB interprets the memory address as a function name. Since there is no function named `0x0000000000006160`, it prints the error message

> `Function "0x0000000000006160" not defined.`

For more information on GDB syntax see the [GDB Command Reference](https://visualgdb.com/gdbreference/commands/break):

[image: Attention]

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to run:

> chmod +x your_filename

Answer (score 1):

The program exiting with code 126 in GDB can occur if the executable file under debug and its sources are in a shared directory in a virtual machine.
I copied the files in a non-shared directory in the same virtual machine and GDB could debug without errors.